# Создать и опубликовать веб-сервис

Tags: 1с, веб-служба

Здравствуйте, сделал все по инструкции ([создать и опубликовать веб-сервис](http://www.lockator.com.ua/config1s/integration/62-web-service.html)), при вводе в адресную строку браузера адреса сервиса просит логин и пароль пользователя, выдает ссылку `*?wsdl`, но вместо xml файла я вижу:

в IE:

> `Невозможно отобразить страницу 
> При попытке доступа к этой странице произошла ошибка, страницу отобразить невозможно.`
>
> `----------------------------------------------------------------------`
>
> `Попробуйте следующее:`
>
> `Откройте домашнюю страницу, затем найдите там ссылки на нужные данные. 
> Нажмите кнопку Обновить или повторите попытку позже.`
>
> `Нажмите кнопку Поиск для поиска сведений в Интернете. 
> Можно также просмотреть список родственных узлов.`
>
> `HTTP 500 - Внутренняя ошибка сервера
> Internet Explorer`

А в хроме:

> `Сервис не найден.`
>
> `An error occurred processing this request.`

**Добавлено.**

httpd.conf копировать не буду, основное:

```
LoadModule php5_module C:/PHP/php5apache2_2.dll  
LoadModule _1cws_module "C:/Program   Files/1cv82/8.2.15.289/bin/wsap22.dll"  
.  
# 'Main' server configuration  
Alias /ws d:/www/ws  
<Location /ws>  
 DirectorySlash Off  
 SetHandler 1cws-process  
 Allow from all  
</Location>  
.
# 1c publication  
Аlias "/test" "D:/www/ws/"  
<Directory "D:/www/ws/">  
    AllowOverride All  
    Options None  
    Order allow,deny  
    Allow from all
    SetHandler 1c-application  
    ManagedApplicationDescriptor "D:/www/ws/default.vrd"  
</Directory>
```

default.vrd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<point xmlns="http://v8.1c.ru/8.2/virtual-resource-system"  
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
        base="/test"  
          ib="Srvr=&quot;127.0.0.1&quot;;Ref=&quot;vesnadev&quot;;"  
        enable="false">  
    <ws>  
        <point name="Test"  
                alias="test.1cws"/>  
    </ws>  
</point>
```

Comment: Покажите содержимое default.vrd, httpd.conf и настроек алиаса базы. 100% где-то не там запятая :-)

Comment: Уточню, URI пространства имен в 1С для веб-сервиса задано http://localhost

Comment: Вроде всё в порядке. А покажите ещё erreor-лог вебсервера

Comment: Последние логи об ошибках задолго до того как я пробовал запускать веб-сервис
:(

Comment: Хм... это плохо. Где-то в логах эта ошибка с подробным описанием должна вывалиться, тем более 500. А если совсем логов нет, это странно выглядит. Хоть favicon недостающий, но проскочит. Проверьте, насколько логируются ошибки. Так-же гляньте журнал регистрации и, на самый крайний случай, технологический журнал платформы. Может-что-то и проскочит.

У других вот что писалось:  http://www.forum.mista.ru/topic.php?id=614545